# how to refer to multiple matrices in a loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have 12 matrices pV1...pV12. I need to change their colnames according to names of TF2Gene which is a list. So I have to repeat this process 12 times. How do I refer these matrices in a loop so that I just have to run a loop instead of calling each of them individually?

```
colnames(pV1)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV2)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV3)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV4)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV5)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV6)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV7)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV8)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV9)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV10)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV11)<-names(TF2Gene)
colnames(pV12)<-names(TF2Gene)
```

Also I have to generate 24 matrices and have to call the command below 24 times,
any shorter way?

```
exprN1.meth.pv <- matrix(nrow=8,ncol=44)
exprN2.meth.pv <- matrix(nrow=8,ncol=44)
exprN4.meth.pv <- matrix(nrow=8,ncol=44)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a list.  Then you can loop over that list either by looping over the index, or looping over the list elements themselves.

Or better yet you can use `lapply`, `sapply`, etc. on the list.

If the matrices are similarly structured, I'd suggest an array (so each 'slice' of the array along the third dimension is one of your current 2d matrices), as it will be faster.

**Edit: How to put them in a list**

The best way is just to create them in a list in the first place.  But if you want to take what you've got, first generate a character vector with the names in it.

```
matNames <- paste0("pV",seq(12))
```

Then use `get`:

```
listOfMat <- lapply( matNames, function(mn) get(mn) )
```

You can then name them with:

```
names(listOfMat) <- matNames
```

Comment: Thanks, and about the matrix creation? Is it possible that way?

Comment: `lapply(1:4, matrix, nrow=8, ncol=44)` gives you a list of 24 matrices.

Comment: Thanks Roland, But again for each of the matrix generated, I have to rename it right?

Comment: Why do you need them to be named?